# Windows Azure websites doesn't allow /Admin page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, admin, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy a web application to Windows Azure Websites and this application has a page /Admin.

After deployment I tried to access this page and I get this response:
"You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

I renamed the controller to TheAdmin and I can access the page with /TheAdmin route. But, renaming won't work for me as this page is a single page application and further access to pages is like /Admin/#/page-title. So, this 'Admin' route is linked to many places, so easiest solution is to allow /Admin access.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it is Azure Websites that is blocking that page. Are you using FormsAuthentication? Also, does the /Admin directory exist on the root of your site?

Comment: Apparently, there was a Admin folder that was left there from an older version. I was updating the site to the new version which does not have the Admin folder. Damn, lost an hour on this. Been a long day. Thanks @Queti!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it is Azure Websites that is blocking that page.

Are you using `FormsAuthentication`? Also, does the `/Admin` directory exist on the root of your site?